Missing moment of inertia of solid sphere by a factor of $2$
The moment of inertia of a solid sphere is given by $\dfrac{2MR^2}{5}$.

(image credits)
Here is the process,
$$\mathrm dm =\frac{M}{V}r^2 \sin(\theta) \, \mathrm dr \, \mathrm d\phi \, \mathrm d\theta$$
$$I=\int_V \mathrm dm \,(r \cos\theta)^2$$
$$I_x = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R \ \frac{M}{V}r^2 \sin(\theta)(r \cos\theta)^2 \, \mathrm dr \, \mathrm d\phi \, \mathrm d\theta.$$
I am getting as $\dfrac{MR^2}{5}$.
I discussed this with my friend; he told me to change the limit of $\theta$ to $-\pi$ to $\pi$ (currently, $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi$).
Also confused as to why I was getting the answer, if I calculate the integral with the same limit about the vertical axis, in that case, it is
$$I_y = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R \ \frac{M}{V}r^2 \sin(\theta)(r \sin\theta)^2 \, \mathrm dr \, \mathrm d\phi \, \mathrm d\theta.$$
I know we can use different methods to calculate, like using rings, disks, and hollow spheres. But I want to know what's wrong with elemental integration.

The mistake is in this part $(r \cos\theta)^2$ which is just $z^2$ but should be

$$y^2+z^2=(r \cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta\sin\phi)^2=r^2-r^2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi$$

and leads to the correct result.

As noticed in the comments, by symmetry
$$\int_D (z^2+y^2)f(r,\theta, \phi)drd\theta d\phi =2\int_D z^2f(r,\theta, \phi)drd\theta d\phi$$
for that reason the correct result is twice of your previous one.

This is the mistake (+1). Alternatively the OP could reason (by symmetry) that the integrals of $z^2$, $y^2$ and $x^2$ over the sphere are all equal. The squared distance to one axis needs the sum of two of those :-).

Yes this is a nice observation! I add that in the answer. Thanks

Actually all is correct. The integration over the angle $\theta$ gives a factor $4/3$. The integration over $r$ gives $R^5/5$ and the integration over $\phi$ gives $2\pi$. So all together is $2MR^2/5$ after the volume vanishes out...
Edit: I see you have to change the differentials for $\phi$ and $\theta$ in your integral. You integrate $\theta$ over $[0,\pi)$ and $\phi$ over $[0,2\pi)$...

"integration over the angle  gives a factor 4/3" -  it gives 2/3 for Iₓ and 4/3 for Iᵧ.
"I see you have to change the differentials for  and  in your integral. You integrate  over [0,) and  over [0,2)." - Its already in that format for both the integrals. Can u please be specific, if I am missing something?
